# How to query the Video Capabilities of an Android device?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-mediacodec, exoplayer

```
public void getCodecInfo() {
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);

        if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();

        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(types[j]);

            Log.d("CodecCapabilities", new Gson().toJson(capabilities));

            //MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities videoCapabilities = capabilities.getVideoCapabilities();
            //Log.d("videoCapabilities", new Gson().toJson(videoCapabilities));
        }
    }
}
```

The above gave me this, what does the following number for profile and level tell me anything related to the video capabilities?

```
{"colorFormats":[21,2130708361],"profileLevels":[{"level":2048,"profile":1},{"level":2048,"profile":2},{"level":2048,"profile":8}],"flags":0}
```

If I uncomment these two lines in the above code, it crashes with this error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.media.MediaCodecInfo$CodecCapabilities.getVideoCapabilities
```

How can I query the android device, to find out the video capabilities? I'd like to know the max video bitrate and video resolution the device is capable to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are testing your code on a device running API < 21? If is the case, the [getVideoCapabilies method is available only on devices running Android >= 21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.VideoCapabilities)

Anyway, to get bitrate and supported width & height [Ranges](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Range) (API >=21 too...Humm may be related to getVideoCapabilies availability... I don't know :) ), you can use :

```
Range<Integer> bitrateRange = videoCapabilities.getBitrateRange();
Range<Integer> heightRange = videoCapabilities.getSupportedHeights();
Range<Integer> widthRange = videoCapabilities.getSupportedWidths();
```

You can take a look at this gist that I published a few days ago to get all capabilities for a given codec (Colors, profiles & levels are printed by names instead of numbers, which could be very helpful): [TestMediaCodecInfoAsyncTask.java](https://gist.github.com/aelqsimi/f773d63fd5f234df7892276e3b05e5f8)