# Exoplayer playback error after interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob, exoplayer, interstitial, exoplayer2.x

I am playing video with ExoPlayer and showing Google AdMob interstitial ad.

After ad has been gone there was trouble to play video and show error like:

```
Playback error.com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.throwDecoderInitError(MediaCodecRenderer.java:441)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:428)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:920)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:503)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:557)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:518)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:301)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc, Format(1, null, video/avc, -1, null, [720, 420, -1.0], [-1, -1])
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:428) 
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:920) 
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:503) 
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:557) 
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:518) 
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:301) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I am using libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.1'
```

Comment: I have this problem too, have you found a solution?

Comment: Please post code snippet of activity with all life cycle methods (where you are showing ads and where you resuming ExoPlayer).

Comment: Remove `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);` if you written anywhere in your code and try it as per this [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/ivm9WQr6T0E/qRjG3SImBAAJ)

Comment: @NikhilSolanki Please refrain from making edits like that - they're not considered good, and it shouldn't have been approved in the first place. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/6296561 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: maybe adding this line under `<Applications...      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`>...</..>` would help.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite hard to debug error, but it can be relatively easy to avoid.

The thing is that `ExoPlayer` is `Google` developed library. Obviously `Google` uses it in its own products. `Google AdMob SDK` uses `ExoPlayer` inside of it. More specifically it uses this player to show some of its interstitial and even banner ads. While on the general app screens usually it works seamlessly without errors and bugs(with a little amount of bugs).

The situation becomes different on the screens with the same `ExoPlayer` player that is being used inside the `AdMob SDK`. Both instances use the same resources - codecs,  renderers etc. thus the device must provide this resources. Number of possible active simultaneous `ExoPlayer` instances may vary from 1(or maybe even 0 on old weak devices) to 10+ - it correlates with maximum number of hardware decoders the device can handle. More about this [here (ExoPlayer issue 273)](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/273).

The possible workaround to this limitation is to set up `ExoPlayer` to use software decoders. It may drastically reduce quality of the experience on weak devices though. How to create software decoder you may find in source code of the `ExoPlayer` in `MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java` class.

Your situation is a bit different because you have no control over at least one of instances - so I cannot predict whether it will work.

Either way I think this issue should be fixed architecturally rather than by the code brute force.

The simplest way is to release your instance of `ExoPlayer` right before the interstitial starts with the `ExoPlayer.release()` and initialize it once more only after the interstitial is finished. Gladly you have all the needed callback methods for that in `AdMob SDK` for interstitials. You may store playback time somewhere to resume from the place user stopped interrupted by an ad.

The more user friendly way is not to interrupt video with ads - show them before and after. Or include ads into video. But is completely dependent on your UI/UX and monetisation system.

I know it is not exactly an answer to your question but rather a thoughts around the theme but I hope it will help you someway.

Comment: Well this is not exact solution answer is Good! :) And I am now looking to find decoder info from [this question]{https://stackoverflow.com/q/51660817/8969251}

Comment: Great info you have provided!

Comment: I wish it was so easy, but in my case it's enough to instantiate interstitial and load the ad. Also I did try releasing Exoplayer and reinstantiating it in ExoPlayer's onError, but it doesn't help. It happens rarely which makes it even more difficult to find the working solution.