# Control the playback time of a video

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm playing a video in `ExoPlayer`. Now I want to distribute a specific time for that video to the user so that the user chooses.
For example, I only want to display 30 seconds to 50 seconds.
In `AndroidStudio` and `JAVA` language.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Possible to duplicate of [Android exoplayer playback error after interstitial ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036849/android-exoplayer-playback-error-after-interstitial-ad)

Comment: @DineshShingadiya that's not duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to `ExoPlayer`! You can handle it on your own.

So use this snippet to solve this problem:

**At the same time with starting video:**

```
videoview.seekTo(SPECIFIED_START_TIME);
```

**Then run this handler:**

```
handler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
       if(videoview.getCurrentPosition() >= DESTINATION_TIME){ // After reaching destination time
           videoview.seekTo(SPECIFIED_START_TIME);
           videoview.pause(); // or stop();
       }
  }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```